# How to copy specific cell content from word document and create new word document

Tags: c#, vb.net

i am working on a project for which i have word document having content in tabular format. for that i need to copy specific cell content from that word file and create new word file with that selected cells. Will it Possible (Or suggest any other method to achieve this).

If Possible, please help me on that.
Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you first need to read the contents of your file you can achieve this by reading Word DOM (see documentation of that library [here](http://www.docentric.com/documentation/programming/reference-guide)). Once you've read the data, you can either (1) create a document from scratch using DOM commands, or insert the new content into a template document to get the final result.

Comment: Through DOM i can create tables in word document and can place images, text in it(this i can also achieve through spire library). But the main problem is that, i want to copy whole cell of table using its cell index which is populated with combination of text and images. is there any way to copy whole cell with text and image..??